# DNSAPI Error 11166 on Windows 2003 member server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

One of my servers is raising an event log error for DNS with the details shown below.

Any suggestions for resolving this?

(Worth mentioning is that 100.150 is a secondary IP address assigned to 100.1)

```
 Event Type:    Warning Event
 Source:    DnsApi 
 Event Category:    None
 Event ID:  11166 
 Date:      27/05/2009
 Time:      10:57:24 
 User:      N/A
 Computer:  TEST-100-1 
 Description: The system failed to register host (A) resource records (RRs) 
 for network adapter with settings:
         Adapter Name :
 {898C2EEB-2269-4A20-9269-33C9D85C42C8}
 Host Name : test-100-1    Primary
 Domain Suffix : mydomain.local    
 DNS server list :
        192.168.100.1, 192.168.100.2    
 Sent update to server :
            192.168.100.150    
 IP Address(es) :
            192.168.100.180
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went for a bit of a "shot-gun" approach to solving this in the end and deleted the DNS entries for the host concerned. For some reason these were showing as "192.168.100.190", which was clearly incorrect.

Doesn't tell us what caused the problem, but it did solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Does the server sending the updates (and failing) have the .1 or the .150 address as its primary DNS server?
Maybe worth checking the DNS server bindings on .1

Answer (score -1):

please check for suggstions/possible solutions here: eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=11166&eventno=3393&source=DnsApi&phase=1